# Write variable after reading .sql query

Tags: python, sql

When I have to pass a parameter before running a sql query, I usually do

```
date = '20220101'

query = f'''SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = '{date}''''
```

On an attempt to reduce the lenght of code, I created a query.sql file with the query above but I'm failing to pass the date variable inside my query, before running the sql.

For reading I'm using

```
sql_query = open("query.sql", "r")
sql_as_string = sql_query.read()

df = pd.read_sql(sql_as_string, conn)
```

Is there a way around, instead of pasting the whole SQL query at my .py code?

I'm using pyodbc, ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server

Comment: Where do you substitute `date` into `sql_as_string`?

Comment: What DBMS are you querying? MySQL, SQLIte, etc.?

Comment: i'm not actually, realized now, i can just use write to overwrite {date} inside my query.sql before reading, don't i?

Comment: You should use a parametrized query, not substitute variables directly into the SQL.

Comment: What you posted is an anti-pattern that would support `SQL Injection`. Parametrization is the antidote: https://python-sql-parameters.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sqlparams.html

Comment: oh, had no idea, ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a parametrized query, not string formatting.

The file should just contain the query, with a `?` placeholder for the variable.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE DATE = ?
```

Then you can do

```
with open("query.sql", "r") as f:
    sql_query = f.read()

df = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn, params=(date, ))
```

Comment: Is there a way to see my "full query" before running? the df is returning empty, like some weird date are being passed by. Btw I'm using `SET @start_date = ?; SET @end_date = ?;` at query.sql and `df_consolidado = pd.read_sql(sql_query, conn, params={start_date, end_date})` at .py is that ok?

Comment: It should be `params = (start_date, end_date)`. Sets aren't ordered.

Comment: I don't know if `pd.read_sql()` allows multiple queries. And what are you expecting to read from a query that just sets variables?

Comment: It worked, changed the params! When you say "Set's aren't ordered" you mean like `(?,?,?)` one after another and not distributed at the sql code?

Comment: `{start_date, end_date}` is a set. `(start_date, end_date)` is a tuple. Tuples remember the order of the elements, sets don't.

Comment: And answering your questions, it's just one query, but with some subselects passing the same date param, thanks Barmar

Comment: `SET @start_date = ?; SET @end_date = ?;` is two statements, that's what I was talking about.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244029/discussion-between-ddddddd-and-barmar).